# cv2.putText text stays in image after next cv2.read

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv

I am working on some code for my master thesis. There are two threads, one does cv2.VideoCapture(), sets the ready Event(), in the second thread while loop waits for the event to be set and then does some image processing. Typical producer, consumer problem.

The problem is, that I am trying to create "model" of the scene, where I would update pixels only in areas without red circle, which i am using as a marker to detect position of an object. I need to remember part of image behind the red marker and then update area everywhere else.

The problem is, that i need to mark the center of the red circle. I use the cv2.circle(). Black dot somehow gets in the model, even though I have never put it there. The cv2.putText() function has the same problem. The code looks like this.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ready = Event()
    vs = VideoStream(0, ready).start()
    v = Vision(vs.read())
    cv2.imshow('firework', v.getImg())

    while cv2.getWindowProperty('firework', cv2.WND_PROP_VISIBLE) >= 1: 
        # data acquisition
        while not ready.isSet():
            pass
        img = vs.read()
        ready.clear()

        # image processing
        v.updateImg(img)
        v.detectRedMarker() # set cX, cY
        mask = v.getROIMask(radius=100)
        v.updateModel(mask) # circle mask, center cX, cY

        # extras
        img = v.putMarkerToImg(img)
        cv2.imshow('firework', img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord(' '):
            break
    vs.stop()
```

Methods in the Vision class...

```
def updateImg(self, img):
    self.img = img
    self.imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(self.img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    return

def getROIMask(self,radius):
    mask = np.zeros((self.imgHeight, self.imgWidth),np.uint8)
    cv2.circle(mask, (self.cX, self.cY), radius, 1, thickness=-1)
    return mask

def updateModel(self,mask):
    modelUpdate = cv2.bitwise_and(self.imgGray, cv2.bitwise_not(mask*255))
    modelOld = cv2.bitwise_and(self.model, (mask*255))
    self.model = cv2.add(modelOld,modelUpdate)
    return
```

As you can see, I put the dot in the center of the red marker after i update the model and then read new image in the next iteration. Somehow the black dot gets into the model. Can anyone please suggest how does this happen?

[Black dot marking the center of red circle somehow gets into the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn4aU.png)

Comment: probably, the memory of img is shared and your putMakerToImg is drawing directly to your model data. Make sure to use a deep copy of the data if you want to keep it and separate it from other computations. The deep copy would be great here: `self.img = img` to some `self.img = deep-copy-of(img)` but I cant tell you how to do it in Python. In C++ it would be mat.copyTo() or mat.clone().

Comment: Thank you very much. I used to code in C, I am new to python, and I somehow forgot about this. The solution was indeed to do a deep copy. Otherwise I was passing only a reference to the object. Thanks

Comment: In C++ it is the same, because cv::Mat is basically only a header to matrix data, which isnt deep-copied by variable copying (which is only a header copying). In the old C interface, there would've been headers/handles and pointers beeing visible.